# combine jQuery statements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a brain dead kind of day and I'm trying to figure out a way to make this smaller and everything I've tried has not worked.   I know there has to be a better way to do this so I figured I would ask here.

Any tips on jQuery caching would be great too (I'm trying to make about 225 lines of jQuery as small as possible so anything can help!

```
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(1)").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(2)").css("text-align","center").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(3)").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(4)").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(5)").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(6)").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(7)").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(8)").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(9)").css("text-align","center").attr("style","border-bottom:1px solid black;");
```

Sorry for my horrendous code, feel free to give me any tips you can think of!

Jeff

Comment: what is the outcome you are expecting also I would use .css rather than .attr  on all itmes

Comment: Basically 1, 3-8 are the same.  2 and 9 are different.  So I want basically make 2 statements out of them where it covers the range of nth-child for those (if possible).  I don't know how to do ranges of nth-child though, so I had to make 9 statements.  I know there has to be a better way its just not coming to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply a CSS class with your border styles to all of the cells (no jquery needed at all for that):

```
<style>
  .tableMap td
  {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: none;
    border-top: none;
  }
</style>
```

Then, afterwards, you can apply your specific styles just to the two items that are needed:

```
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(2)").css("text-align","center");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(9)").css("text-align","center").attr("style","border-right:none;");
```

A good thing to remember is to only use javascript/jQuery when you need it. Use straight up HTML/CSS whenever you can, your site will perform much better that way.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like if you  do

```
$(".tableMap td").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
```

then

```
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(2),.tableMap td:last").css("text-align","center");
```

it would be much simpler

Answer (score 0):

untested - but i tjink you can see what i am getting at...

```
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(1)").attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td").children().lt(9).gt(1).attr("style","border-right:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;");
$(".tableMap td:nth-child(9)").css("text-align","center").attr("style","border-bottom:1px solid black;");
```